# Trying to code a method to generate all integer partitions without repetition and using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to code a method that generates partitions of an integer, but I'm having trouble doing it by myself and no one from school seems to know how to do it so I am coming here for help because I'm really trying and I'm not getting anything done.

So, as an output example we have this, for the number 4: Partitions of 4

4

3 1

2 2

2 1 1

1 1 1 1

The code I have so far is:

```
static void partition(int[] p, int n, int m, int i) {

        if (n == 0){
            for (int j= 0; j < m; j++)
            System.out.print(p[j]+" ");

        System.out.println();
        }
        else
            for (int k= m; k  >=0; k--) {
                p[i]= k;
                partition(p, n-k, Math.min(n-k, k), i+1);
            }
```

It's not working but I'm not quite sure why so if anyone can help by pointing it out and helping me fix it or suggest a better way to do it it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: it would be helpful if you explained the parameters...  i have figured out what the array is used for but would be guessing on the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The loop to output the array should go up to `i` instead of `m`:

```
for (int j= 0; j < i; j++)
```